# VueJS Trying to capture enter press on child component before parent component handles enter

Tags: vuejs2

I have an auto complete input that when I press enter in this input, it is to emit its value to the parent component and then the parent submit action should be handled. However it appears that the parent is first receiving the enter key submiting the form and then the child component will finally emit the value meaning the data doesnt get updated until after it is needed.

I have an example code pen I made up

[codepen](https://codepen.io/stedotmartin/pen/aRRWby?editors=1111)

```
Vue.component('child', { 
  data () {
    return {
      someData: ""
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input @keyup.enter.capture="enterPressed" v-model="someData" />
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    enterPressed(){
      this.$emit('updateData',this.someData)
      console.log('CHILD: enter pressed')
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('parent', { 
  data () {
    return {
      lastGo: null,
      parentData: "init"
    }
  },
  template: `
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="go">
    <child @updateData="updateData"></child>
    <button @click="go">Go</button>
    <p>Parent data: <b>{{parentData}}</b></p>
    <p>Last go: <b>{{lastGo}}</b></p>
    </form>
  `,
  methods: {
    updateData(data){
      this.parentData = data;
    },
   go(){
     this.lastGo = this.parentData;
     console.log("go: "+this.parentData)
   }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this, I feel maybe that my pattern just isn't going to work, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to work around is using `@input` event in child component

```
Vue.component('child', { 
  data () {
    return {
      someData: ""
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input @input="onInput" v-model="someData" />
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
    onInput(){
      console.log('CHILD: enter pressed')
      this.$emit('updateData',this.someData)
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/XxxVRb)